# Is there an easy process to figure out a song's specific genre?

Tags: genre

I always hear music that is apparently one genre, but it's actually another for some reason.

For example, earlier today I was listening to Infected Mushroom and I noticed some of their songs are verging on what most people would consider dubstep, but Infected Mushroom is classified as things such as psytrance and glitch-hop.

Is there a process to easily break large genres (e.g., electronic) down into smaller and smaller genres to figure something like this out?

Comment: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-any-objective-genre-like-categorization-of-musical-works may also be of interest.

Comment: @topomorto That answers my question pretty well. Didn't find it from searching for some reason.